# Eclipse Tool tip

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to implement a tool-tip in wizard for one of my widget.I like to have a tool tip which looks like Eclipse tool tip (when hovering any thing in  java editor tool tip will be displayed ,like that tool tip required) .
Is it possible to implement in Wizard ?
If yes, how it can be implemented.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Control.getToolTipText()` to set a tool tip. Can you do this with the controls created in the wizard? If not, can you explain more how your controls are created?